# forcing all calls to be dialed by hangouts

Tags: calls, google-hangouts

How do we configure the phone so that tapping on a contact number triggers the hangouts app to place to call? ( instead of the local carrier kicking in such as at&t. )

If I'm not mistaking, there was such an option, which I think I opted out, or I'm totally dreaming cause I can't find that darn setting.   :)

Currently, my phone is configured so that only the international calls are routed thru hangouts.

thanks

note 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the same problem before. I During setup, the Google Voice app (this is what you mean, right) asks whether you want all calls router, just international calls, or no calls routed through it. If you didn't select All calls during setup, it cannot be found in settings. But the solution is to use the Google Voice toggle widget (looks just like the Google voice all, 1x1). Place it on your home screen, then tap on it until you see the toast that says Route All Calls through Google Voice (or something like that).

Otherwise, if you want everything to be routed through **Google Hangouts**, you have two options. But note that this routes calls through your data plan, not your phone plan. Both solutions require use of the Google Hangouts Dialer app. Download it from the play store. The first method is simple. Replace your dialer with Google Hangouts Dialer. When you open the app, it takes you to a tab in Hangouts that contains a dialpad, or your call log. If you do not see the dial pad, click the dialpad button at the bottom. Then dial, like you normally would. The second is a little more complicated, but it allows you to use your existing dialer. Clear your app defaults for both Hangouts Dialer, and your native Dialer app. Then when you dial a phone number, your phone should prompt whether to call using your phone app, or Hangouts Dialer. Select Hangouts Dialer.

If this helped you, please select the green Check mark(✔️✅) on the left of the answer, so the community knows this is the best answer. Thanks

Comment: Very thorough. I cannot test what you suggested now since I don't have that phone yet. Thank you for the details and the reminder about the green-check-mark. So, the things to do is 1) get the "Google Voice toggle widget", and run it to answer that setting question to set "I want only the international calls to be routed by Google Voice".  AND at that time, we should be done with that widget, right? I gather that this is kind of like back-door setting tool that allows you to get to the Google Voice App's initial set up config values and therefore we can delete it off the phone, once we done

Comment: Yes. That's perfect.